# extract text from pptx, ppt, docx, doc and msg files python windows

Tags: python, powerpoint, docx

Is there a way to extract text from pptx, ppt, docx, doc and msg files on windows machine? I have few hundreds of these file and need some programmatic way. I would prefer Python. But I am open to other suggestions

I searched online and saw some discussions but they were applicable to linux machines

Comment: I'd think Visual Basic for Applications would be simpler to implement because it gives you access to MS's document object models.

Comment: Have you seen this `python-pptx`: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#extract-all-text-from-slides-in-presentation? Or `python-docx`: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html#really-opening-a-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Word

I tried for word something with python-docx, to install it write pip install python-docx. I had a word doc called example with 4 lines of text in there that were grabbed in the right way like you see in the output below.
[image]

```
from docx import Document

d = Document("example.docx")

for par in d.paragraphs:
    print(par.text)
```

output (the example.docx content):

```
Titolo
Paragrafo 1 a titolo di esempio
This is an example of text
This is the final part, just 4 rows
```

### Join all the text of docx in a folder

```
import os
from docx import Document

files = [f for f in os.listdir() if ".docx" in f]
text_collector = []
whole_text = ''
for f in files:
    doc = Document(f)
    for par in doc.paragraphs:
        text_collector.append(par.text)

for text in text_collector:
    whole_text += text + "\n"

print(whole_text)
```

### As above, but with choise

In this code you are asked to choose the file that you want to join froma list that appears of the docx file in the folder.

```
import os
from docx import Document

files = [f for f in os.listdir() if ".docx" in f]

for n,f in enumerate(files):
    print(n+1,f)
print()
print("Write the numbers of files you need separated by space")
inp = input("Which files do you want to join?")

desired = (inp.split())
desired = map(lambda x: int(x), desired)
list_to_join = []
for n in desired:
    list_to_join.append(files[n-1])


text_collector = []
whole_text = ''
for f in list_to_join:
    doc = Document(f)
    for par in doc.paragraphs:
        text_collector.append(par.text)

for text in text_collector:
    whole_text += text + "\n"

print(whole_text)
```